# Cannot run the repeat loop in full : Error in D[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r

Good afternoon !

Under R , i developed the following script where **the first function** `Initial_search_domain_function_pdim` samples `N` vectors from the `n-dimensional` space `(n=length(MIN))`. Those vectors are stored in rows of the matrix `X`. After that , we compute for each row the image with the function `Objfun=Sphere_1_pdim` and we add those images at the last column of `X` ( `result1` variable ).

In the next step , we arrange `result1` based on the `Objfun` column decreasly and we report the `p` first rows ( `m2` variable).

For each column of `m2` , we compute the minimum and maximum then we return the `result` ( Two columns `L_bound` and `U_bound`).

Concerning **the second function**  , it will call `Initial_search_domain_function_pdim` recursively.

```
Sphere_1_pdim = function (x) return(sum(x^2)) 

Initial_search_domain_function_pdim <- function(N, p, MIN, MAX, Objfun) { 
  
  c=length(MIN)
  
  r=N
  
  X=runif(N,min=MIN[1],max=MAX[1])
  
  for (i in 2:c){
    
    X=cbind(X,runif(N,min=MIN[i],max=MAX[i]))
    
  }
  
  
  result1=cbind(X,apply(X,1,Objfun))
  colnames(result1)[ncol(result1)]="Objfun"
  #print(result1)
  m1=result1[order(result1[,c+1], decreasing = FALSE),]
  #print("m1")
  #print(m1)
  m2=m1[1:p,]
  
  L_bound=apply(m2[,-ncol(m2)],2,min)
  U_bound=apply(m2[,-ncol(m2)],2,max)  
  r1=t(rbind(L_bound,U_bound)) 
  #print(X)
  #print(m1) 
  #print(r1)  
  
  print("m2 : it contains at rows the p lowest 3-dimensional vectors with their associated objfun values")
  print(m2)  
  
  tmp=apply(r1,2,Objfun)
  result=rbind(r1,tmp)
  rownames(result)[nrow(result)]="Objfun"
  return(result)  
  
}

Initialization <- function(Nbre_init_iteration,N,p,MIN,MAX,Objfun) {
  
  D=Initial_search_domain_function_pdim (N,p,MIN,MAX,Objfun)
  print("N_iter")
  print(Nbre_init_iteration)
  Init_sol=D[,D[nrow(D),] == min(D[nrow(D),])]
  print("init_sol")
  print(Init_sol)
  D=D[-nrow(D),]
  
  repeat{
    
    MIN_t=D[,1]-p/N
    MAX_t=D[,2]+p/N
    Nbre_init_iteration=Nbre_init_iteration-1
    
    if (Nbre_init_iteration == 1){
      return(Init_sol)
      break 
    }
    
    D=Initialization(Nbre_init_iteration,N,p,MIN_t,MAX_t,Objfun)
    
  }
  
}
```

Example of output :

```
    Sphere_1_pdim = function (x) return(sum(x^2)) 
    res=Initial_search_domain_function_pdim (N=8, p=5, c(-4.5,-4.5,-4.5), c(4.5,4.5,4.5),Sphere_1_pdim)
    res

[1] "m2 : it contains at rows the p lowest 3-dimensional vectors with their associated objfun values"

              X                          Objfun
[1,] -0.1883397  0.0635250 -2.6128179  6.866325
[2,] -1.8906414 -2.0070674  0.1256882  7.618642
[3,]  1.3009347 -3.0388569  1.7264074 13.907565
[4,]  4.0384596  0.6102089  0.3367505 16.794912
[5,] -1.1818269  2.6019059 -3.7743794 22.412569
         L_bound   U_bound
X      -1.890641  4.038460
       -3.038857  2.601906
       -3.774379  1.726407
Objfun 27.055117 26.059553
```

**The main problem is with the second function** `Initialization` , For example :

```
Initialization(Nbre_init_iteration=3,N=80, p=2, rep(-6,2), rep(6,2),Sphere_1_pdim)
     L_bound   U_bound
X  0.2036010 0.3021338
  -0.7232958 0.9235409
[1] "N_iter"
[1] 3
[1] "init_sol"
         X                   tmp 
 0.2036010 -0.7232958  0.5646102 
     L_bound    U_bound
X 0.18878229 0.19032993
  0.01130187 0.03873859
[1] "N_iter"
[1] 2
[1] "init_sol"
         X                   tmp 
0.18878229 0.01130187 0.03576649 
Error in D[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

This means i can't complete the number of iterations which is `Nbre_init_iteration=3`. How can i solve this error ?

I hope my question is clear.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I never seen a function calling itself within. Are you sure this is part of the code?
I am reffering to the first block of code, last line of the function Initialization():
Initialization <- function(...) {
....
   { 
   ...
   D=Initialization(Nbre_init_iteration,N,p,MIN_t,MAX_t,Objfun)
   }
}

Comment: Function calling itself is called recursive function - not very popular but it has its usage
https://techterms.com/definition/recursive_function#:~:text=A%20recursive%20function%20is%20a,9%2C%20to%20the%20number%2010.

Comment: @Sinh Nguyen , I will use a while loop instead !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code here:

- Please avoid using `=` for assignment variable - instead using `<-` would make the code easier to read overall in R. [this is preferable coding stlye in R as `=` can have multiple usage in R - though no obilgation here - choose what your prefer]
- Please have proper space like writing a paragraph, have space after `,` would make code more readable.

Further comment related to code is added comment inline - Please review and as I am not sure what you want to achieve with your functions so please check these debug information and fix it or provide more detail of what you want to achieve.

```
Initialization <- function(Nbre_init_iteration, N, p, MIN, MAX, Objfun) {
  
  N_iteration <- Nbre_init_iteration
  D <- Initial_search_domain_function_pdim (N, p, MIN, MAX, Objfun)
  print("N_iter")
  print(N_iteration)
  Init_sol <- D[, D[nrow(D),] == min(D[nrow(D),])]
  print("init_sol")
  print(Init_sol)
  # this causing the D losing rows
  D <- D[-nrow(D),]
  
  repeat{
    # I added this print for debug purpose to see at which call it causing errors
    # turn out at one point your D matrix is just a vector so it causing error
    # once it reach that. It is due to the return of this call
    # Initialization(N_iteration = 2, N = 80, p = 2,
    #    MIN_t = c(0.3358803, -1.132672),
    #    MAX_t = c(0.9187763, 0.3396840), Objfun = Sphere_1_pdim)
    # Error occured at 2nd repeat loop of original Nbre_init_iteration == 3
    print(paste0("Iteration: ", N_iteration,
                 "- original Nbre_init_iteration: ", Nbre_init_iteration))
    print(paste0("D matrix - original Nbre_init_iteration: ",
                 Nbre_init_iteration))
    print(D)
    # These command trigger errors as D is only a vector not a matrix anymore
    MIN_t <- D[, 1]-p/N
    MAX_t <- D[, 2]+p/N
    N_iteration = N_iteration-1
    
    if (N_iteration == 1){
      return(Init_sol)
      # break statement will never be reached. Function stop at return statement
      break
    }
    
    D <- Initialization(N_iteration, N, p, MIN_t, MAX_t, Objfun)
  }
}
```

Here is the output with debug information

```
> Initialization(Nbre_init_iteration=3,N=80, p=2, rep(-6,2), rep(6,2),Sphere_1_pdim)
[1] "m2 : it contains at rows the p lowest 3-dimensional vectors with their associated objfun values"
              X                 Objfun
[1,] -0.0502898 0.01622357 0.002792268
[2,]  0.4806404 0.42392285 0.410725766
[1] "trial"
            L_bound   U_bound
X      -0.050289801 0.4806404
        0.016223573 0.4239228
Objfun  0.002792268 0.4107258
[1] "N_iter"
[1] 3
[1] "init_sol"
           X                    Objfun 
-0.050289801  0.016223573  0.002792268 
[1] "Iteration: 3- original Nbre_init_iteration: 3"
[1] "D matrix - original Nbre_init_iteration: 3"
      L_bound   U_bound
X -0.05028980 0.4806404
   0.01622357 0.4239228
[1] "m2 : it contains at rows the p lowest 3-dimensional vectors with their associated objfun values"
              X                    Objfun
[1,] 0.01276158  0.001610479 0.0001654515
[2,] 0.01538297 -0.008393134 0.0003070805
[1] "trial"
             L_bound      U_bound
X       0.0127615792 0.0153829720
       -0.0083931344 0.0016104787
Objfun  0.0002333026 0.0002392295
[1] "N_iter"
[1] 2
[1] "init_sol"
            X                      Objfun 
 0.0127615792 -0.0083931344  0.0002333026 
[1] "Iteration: 2- original Nbre_init_iteration: 2"
[1] "D matrix - original Nbre_init_iteration: 2"
       L_bound     U_bound
X  0.012761579 0.015382972
  -0.008393134 0.001610479
[1] "Iteration: 2- original Nbre_init_iteration: 3"
[1] "D matrix - original Nbre_init_iteration: 3"
            X                      Objfun 
 0.0127615792 -0.0083931344  0.0002333026 
Error in D[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Comment: Hi @SinhNguyen , where is the object `global_track` . I got this error :                            
  `Error in print("global_track : ", global_track) : 
  object 'global_track' not found`

Comment: Sorry! It suppose to be removed from the code - It was my testing of variable calling through recursive function - it really tricky to debug recursive function. I updated the code to get rid of `global_track` You can just delete the line you got.

Comment: i solved the pb using a simple while loop . Thank you for your precious help !

Answer (score 1):

If I remove the call to Initialization within the Initialization function, it runs for me:

```
Initialization <- function(Nbre_init_iteration,N,p,MIN,MAX,Objfun) {
        
                D=Initial_search_domain_function_pdim (N,p,MIN,MAX,Objfun)
                print("N_iter")
                print(Nbre_init_iteration)
                Init_sol=D[,D[nrow(D),] == min(D[nrow(D),])]
                print("init_sol")
                print(Init_sol)
                D=D[-nrow(D),]
                
                repeat{
                        
                        MIN_t=D[,1]-p/N
                        MAX_t=D[,2]+p/N
                        Nbre_init_iteration=Nbre_init_iteration-1
                        
                        if (Nbre_init_iteration == 1){
                                return(Init_sol)
                                break 
                        }

                        ## remove the line below: ##
                        #D=Initialization(Nbre_init_iteration,N,p,MIN_t,MAX_t,Objfun)
                        
                }  
        
        
        
}

Initialization(Nbre_init_iteration=3,N=80, p=3, rep(-6,2), rep(6,2),Sphere_1_pdim)

[1] "m2 : it contains at rows the p lowest 3-dimensional vectors with their associated objfun values"
               X               Objfun
[1,] -0.06179717  0.6472889 0.4228018
[2,] -0.10868843 -0.7269198 0.5402256
[3,]  0.69282762  0.4582135 0.6899697
[1] "N_iter"
[1] 3
[1] "init_sol"
         X                Objfun 
-0.1086884 -0.7269198  0.5402256 
         X                Objfun 
-0.1086884 -0.7269198  0.5402256
```

Comment: Hi @RosalieBruel. I will use a while loop instead of recursive call. Thank you again !